# copy array in to another array using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, copy, stack

following are the steps of the program I'm trying to make

1. catch String using Scanner
2. pass that String to a method in another class
3. separate characters of that String in to an array using `.toCharArray()`
4. copy contents of that array to another array using a for loop

but this array giving me a null pointer exception. what am i doing wrong? (ignore the class naming i know it's stupid but i have to do it this way because my teacher wants it that way)

main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class _01 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        int size = name.length();

        _02 process = new _02(size);

        process.push(name);

    }

}
```

other class with the array:

```
    public class _02 {

        int maxsize;
        int top;
        char arrayStack[];

        public _02(int size) {

            maxsize = size;
            top = -1;

            }

        public void push(String letters) {

            char temp[]= letters.toCharArray();

            for (int c=0;c<temp.length;c++) {

                temp[c] = arrayStack[++top];

            }

       }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment is reversed - you want to assign **from** temp (right side of assignment) **to** arrayStack (left side of assignment).  Also, you need to initialize arrayStack, e.g. `arrayStack = new char[temp.length]` - right now it's null.

Answer (score 0):

```
char arrayStack[]; // this is not initialized.


arrayStack[] = new char[temp.length] // inside the push() method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays need to be initialized in Java; simply declaring an array yields a field initialized to `null`. Once you change the class to properly initialize `arrayStack`, you don't need the `maxsize` field, since it will be the same as `arrayStack.length`. You also have your assignment reversed in the `push` method. Finally, since you have a maximum array size, you might want to avoid throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and instead throw a more semantically meaningful exception, or else simply drop the extra characters or grow the stack (in which case the constructor arg is an initial size). For that, you will need some range checking. Finally, the logic is cleaner if you initialize `top` to 0 instead of `-1` and use `top++` instead of `++top` (or, better, use the built-in API for copying pieces of an array).

```
public class _02 {
    int top;
    char arrayStack[];

    public _02(int size) {
        arrayStack = new char[size];
        top = 0;
    }

    public void push(String letters) {
        char temp[]= letters.toCharArray();
        int len = temp.length;

        // do some range checking
        if (top + len >= arrayStack.length) {
            // silently ignore the extra characters
            len = arrayStack.length - top;
            // an alternative would be to throw a "stack full" exception
            // yet another alternative would be to grow the stack
        }

//        for (int c=0; c<len; c++) {
//            arrayStack[top++] = temp[c];
//        }
        // don't use a loop--use the API!
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, arrayStack, top, len);
        top += len;
    }
}
```